# Is there a good way to group a series of def functions in python that run one after another with Tkinter?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am working with a series of tkinter python function blocks and I am wondering if there is a better way to do this that is more clean. I am not fully versed with the Class nor def **init** methodologies but have looked at them some but still don't quite get it.

Here is the code that I am sampling:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

Save Button:

```
def SaveProfile():
    print("-----------------------------------------")
    print("First Name: %s" % (firstname.get()))
    global Firstname
    Firstname = firstname.get()
    root.destroy()
```

Cancel Button:

```
def Quit():
    root.destroy()
```

Selection Box:

```
root = tk.Tk()
# def NewProfile():
label = tk.Label(text="Create New Profile:").grid(row=0, column=1)

tk.Label(root, text="First Name: ").grid(row=1)
firstname = tk.Entry(root)
firstname.insert(10, "Andrew")
firstname.grid(row=1, column=1)

# Buttons
tk.Button(root, text='Save', command=SaveProfile).grid(row=5,column=0,sticky=tk.W,pady=4)
tk.Button(root, text='Cancel', command=Quit).grid(row=5,column=1,sticky=tk.W,pady=4)

tk.mainloop()
```

Is there a good way to merge these all together into one cell rather then many? Is it possible to put the selection box into a def function block? When I try I get an error stating that firstname isn't identified.

Comment: Merge into one cell? What's a cell?

Comment: I am using Jupyter Notebooks. So one block of code.

Comment: You don't need to change anything about the code to do that. You can put multiple functions in a cell if you want. Or the entire program.